# Raycast from vertex to vertex

Tags: scripting

I'm new to scripting in blender and I wanted to make a very specific addon, which makes it very hard to find anything useful.
Basically, there's a loop that goes thru every vertex at the top of the mesh, makes a raycast down starting from the vertex's position, goes to the bottom of the mesh, and searches for vertices on the X and Y axis in a specified radius. If a vertex is found, it's X and Y coords are set to be exactly where the ray is.

Let me know if blender or an addon already has a feature similar to this.
Sorry for the trouble if there's a simple explanation, this whole blender scripting confuses me.